# Conditional pagebreak depending on position on page

Tags: page-breaking, conditionals

Is there a way to say, add a newline here, if there are less than x empty lines before the next assumed pagebreak? something like

```
\newpageIfThisLineIsLinesAwayFromBottomLessThan{5}
```

I know that this goes against the latex approach, but I guess for this particular setup thats the best way to have the automatic flexibility while guiding LaTeX a bit into the right direction.

Edit: I did not have success with the Needspace Package, maybe there is something else similar?

Comment: This sounds like exactly what `needspace` does. What about it did not give what you wanted?

Comment: some strange corner cases of using it environments with itemize and verbatim - guess its more promising to search for a completely different approach first (if there is any)

Comment: @user2567875: Would you please share your "strange corner cases"?

Comment: @user2567875: As Werner suggested, It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem. I have used the `needspace` package often and has worked for me, but is difficult to help you without a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Comment: Sorry not allowed to share the file in this state, maybe after publishing. The problem: as soon I try to "minimize it" it does work. Threfore I said strange corner cases. I would rather try a new approach than debugging this one now.

Comment: needspace (or its star form) does about a good a job as can be done to answer the question as asked, although it's the wrong question, that isn't how tex works. At the time macros in the text are expanded page breaking has not been considered and so there is no real notion of the current point or how far that is from the bottom of the page. the TeX way would be to put a penalty  favouring a page break and balance that with allowing the glue at the bottom of the page to stretch, balance the cost of stretching against the penalty specified for breaking the page  to control where the page breaks